# Do I need to maintain ReSharper's dotsettings.user file in Source Control?

Tags: c#, version-control, resharper

I noticed ReSharper has created a `dotsettings.user` in my Source folder.

[image: file.sln.dotSettings.user]

1. Do I need to keep this in my Source Control (TFS)?
2. If I exclude it, what are the consequences?
3. If I get latest on another machine, will my customized ReSharper settings be lost? Or does ReSharper re-create the settings from some other local file?

Comment: The main reason to include it would be to standardize across a team, from what I can tell. Otherwise, there's no reason.

Comment: I always exclude .user files as a rule, but really there's no standard answer here.

Comment: You're wrong @Magus, the .user file should never be checked in. You standardize aross a team by checking in the dotsettings file _not_ ending with .user

Answer (score 160, accepted):

No, the `dotSettings.user` file should be *excluded* from source control. It has user specific information in it, and shouldn't be shared, e.g. bookmarks, unit test session windows.

The `.dotSettings` contains project or solution specific settings that can be shared with the team, e.g. naming standards or braces layout. If you wish to share these amongst teams then the file should be included.

Answer (score 16):

No, you shouldn't do so, as ReSharper Help says.

> The corresponding settings file .sln.DotSettings is saved in the solution folder.
>
> As soon as this file is added to your VCS and the team members get it, they will have settings from this file applied automatically without reloading the solution.[1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html#solution-team-shared-layer)
>
> The corresponding settings file .sln.DotSettings.user is saved in the solution folder. You should not add it to your VCS.[2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html#solution-personal-layer)

The [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html) explains ReSharper setting layers in details, which answers your questions as well.

Comment: Really good explanation. Makes sense to use that reasoning to check in the DotSettings file for team level enforcement of settings though.